# In a template, how to create if statement when model.value == "str"

Tags: django

In my detail.html template i'm trying to create 2 separate views depending if the books genre is either fiction or nonfiction.  How do i create the if statement for this in this scenario

```
{% if genre == Fiction %}
    {% for x in book %}

    <h1>{{x.title}}: </h1>
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}

<h1> This is the other sections</h1>
{% endif %}
```

My book model has a value of "genre" that takes a string.  How to i access this in the "if" statement in my templates?

EDIT:

views.py

```
    class BookDetailView(TemplateView):                                       
        template_name = 'app/detail.html'                                

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):                                 
            context = super(BookDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
            context['book'] = Book.objects.filter(key=self.kwargs['key'])
```

I know I should be using detailviews to do this but this is a snippet of a much larger project, and went with template views instead

This is to show detail of a book, but want the page to look different depending on genre

Comment: what are you passing into your template's context? Show us the view and the Book model. I don't understand `for x in book` if `book` is a `Book` instance. When you say "my book model has a value of 'genre' that takes a string" do you mean your `Book` model has a field `genre` that is a `CharField`?

Comment: but in general {% if book.genre == "fiction" %} would give you what you want

Comment: I've tried `{% if book.genre == "fiction" %}` and doesn't work,  context `book` is returning only one book and when i click on a book with genre equal to fiction it wont work.. and yes genre is a charfield

Comment: `Book.objects.filter(...` will return a queryset, you should use `Book.objects.get` if you want a specific one. Then you should be able to access the genre as @dirkgroten said

Comment: your `book` context isn't returning one book, it's returning a queryset. You should return a single instance and then you won't have to do `for x in book` either.

Comment: Ah i see, that worked thank you

Comment: just want to add point, you need to return context. don't see  any return your code. Hope you doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Book.objects.filter(...` will return a queryset, use `Book.objects.get(...` to get a specific one.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):                                 
    context = super(BookDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
    context['book'] = Book.objects.get(key=self.kwargs['key'])
    return context
```

Then access it directly and no for-loop is needed.

```
{% if book.genre == "fiction" %}
    <h1>{{book.title}}: </h1>
{% else %}
    <h1> This is the other sections</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It probably make sense to place this logic on the model. `def is_fiction(self):` and call `{% if book.is_fiction %}` in the template code. This allows the logic to travel around wherever the model may be and it isn't confined to just the template.

Answer (score 2):

For now I am assuming that you have a models.py somewhat as:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

and views.py as:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import Book

class Books(View):
    def get(self, request):
        all_books = Book.objects.all() # assuming you are fetching all the books
        context = {'books': all_books}
        return render(request, 'Your_Template.html', context=context)
```

Now in template (Your_Template.html):

```
{% for book in books %}
    {% ifequal book.genre|stringformat:'s' 'fiction' %}
        {{ book.name }} is of genre 'fiction'.
    {% else %}
        {{ book.name }} is of genre '{{ book.genre }}'.
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```